# Unwanted grounding from metal screws in metal boxes

Tags: electrical, grounding

In the winter I repeatedly get intense static discharge shocks from the faceplate screws in my basement light switch panels (which are grounded metal boxes, unlike the plastic ones used in non-basement locations). Is there any good reason not to replace the screws holding the faceplates on with non-conductive ones? Are matching (size and thread) plastic screws available? Or is there some other clever solution to the problem that's not ugly or dangerous?

Comment: Metal faceplates have to be grounded, and right now it's grounded via those screws. You should replace the entire faceplate with plastic if you want to avoid the issue.

Comment: The faceplates are normal plastic, not metal. It's only the boxes and screws that are conductive and grounded.

Comment: Being careful not to touch the screw of course works, but when reaching for a switch in the dark it's hard to avoid without a lot of care.

Comment: yes you can get plastic screws. I doubt you'll find them locally, google "plastic wall plate screws" and order online.   A healthy dab of paint might do the job as well.

Comment: @agentp: Thanks. The screw heads are painted, but I think there's sufficient scratching from the screwdriver to leave a tiny metal surface exposed. Or the voltage is just sufficiently high that the paint doesn't matter.

Comment: Ah, sorry, for some I saw "metal" multiple times so I assumed metal everywhere. In that case, plastic machine screws are the way you seek.

Comment: if you have carpets, try spraying with diluted "downy" fabric softener

Answer (score 2):

I think the clever solution you're looking for is covering the screw with a square of white electrical tape to prevent yourself from touching the screw.

You could also purchase [nylon 6-32 machine screws with a flat head](https://m.grainger.com/mobile/product/4DJG3?cm_mmc=PPC:%20Google%20PLA&s_kwcid=AL!2966!3!166592851194!!!g!82128572157!&ef_id=WYxGSQAAAEAHIXHb:20180109010705:s&kwid=productads-adid%5E166592851194-device%5Em-plaid%5E82128572157-sku%5E4DJG3-adType%5EPLA) which are non-conductive.

That only fixes the sympom of the problem, but not the cause. Your excessive static electricity is from low relative humidity levels in the air. Increase it to 30-40% RH and you'll be happier.

Comment: The white electrical tape approach should work but it's mildly ugly and will get progressively uglier as stuff sticks to the edges. I agree the low humidity is a problem, but that's hard to avoid with the current weather event in the eastern US. It will probably be over soon, but it would be nice to avoid the issue recurring in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to humidify the room or house, so you don't build up as much static in the first place. If you remove the metal screws in the faceplates, you'll just get shocks somewhere else. Get a humidifier, either a small one for the room or one that attaches to the furnace.

In the winter, indoor humidity levels can drop below 20% - ideally they should be between 40% and 60%.

Comment: Shocks "somewhere else" are a lot less intense than from a direct metallic path to a grounding rod.

Comment: You can get a "static" shock from *anything* that happens to be at a different potential, whether it's metallic or non-conductive.